# Angular 2. Run on shared hosting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, hosting, shared-hosting

I am started with AngularJS 2:

- Instaled NodeJS
- Downloaded start project
- Run on Node

**All works!**

However how to run it in production on shared hosting (without Node ant not on vps)? How to open in browser by clicking on index.html?

Comment: hi, did you find the answer. same problem here

Comment: Yes, [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) . You need to build your app for runing in host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a simple Angular2 app on a shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854368/how-to-deploy-a-simple-angular2-app-on-a-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to command `ng build --prod`.

This will build your app into the dist folder.
Copy the contents of your dist folder to the public directory of your shared hosting.

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40854458/2816279

Comment: Works great, if Angular 2 CLI was used, otherwise it returns `You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.`. Any recommendation on how to build a non CLI Angular project?

Comment: @Kristjan O. are you in the same boat as the OP where you based a project on a starter project and now can't build it? Where did you download your starter project? If it was the Angular Class starter project use: `npm build:aot:prod`. Check the `project.json` file for any build commands. Maybe query on the project page for the starter project you downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need anything else other than importing a few javascript files in your index.html file.

Check this [live example](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/js/plnkr.html)

Download it from [plunkr](https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/js/plnkr.html) here and extract it to your required folder in your shared hosting, that's all.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: What you have is Angular 1, not 2 as wanted.

Comment: live example link is not found.