# Deploy Angular 2 for production

Tags: angular

I have an existing Angular 2 project and I want to deploy it for production mode. I have run these commands and when I open the index.html file inside the `dist` folder I get this message `app works!` instead of my real application.

```
ng init
ng build -prod --aot
```

How can I deploy this existing application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a simple Angular2 app on a shared hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854368/how-to-deploy-a-simple-angular2-app-on-a-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 1):

You need a webserver to serve the content of your app. Run it locally or deploy your dist folder somewhere in the web.