# How can I deploy my Angular 5 web app to my panel

Tags: angular, server, cpanel

I've been trying to deploy my finished angular project to my free panel hosting. I'm a newbie in Angular, and I can only host using Firebase which is quite simple with Angular CLI.

I'd appreciate it if I could get a detailed explanation or a post/blog that explains it in details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy a simple Angular2 app on a shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854368/how-to-deploy-a-simple-angular2-app-on-a-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 4):

- `ng build --prod` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build
- copy files from your dist folder to the host
- done

The dist folder will contain static files including an index.html . This is all you need to host your app.

Answer (score -1):

You can deploy to Netlify.
Find the reference:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/deploying-an-angular-app-to-netlify

I have hosted my angular website, you can check:
https://christian-matrimony.netlify.app/#/home